# Setting the limit on the while function

Tags: php

Kindly let me know how can I put the limit on the record in the below function.  I want to fetch all the record but one first page I want to show 5 only. Like pagination.

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)) ){

}
```

Comment: You should use `LIMIT` in your SQL query.

Comment: He wants to fetch all :-) Otherwise I would say LIMIT, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$times = 5;

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)) && $times-- > 0){

}
```

However, this is **not recommended**! Use a `limit` clause in the SQL query instead, to avoid using a lot of CPU power for getting records you're not going to use anyway.

Comment: You're not going to shift the `--` over to make the "approaches" operator (`-->`)? :-) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/01/somelastminutefeatures.aspx

Comment: @glowcoder Oh boy! That one made my day. Knowing MS, they could probably actually implement such an operator one day...

Answer (score 1):

```
$limit  = 0;
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)) && $limit < 5){
$limit++;
}
```